# RxJs observe several observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

In an older version of RxJs I used the following approach:

```
combineLatest([
  this.state.select(selector1),
  this.stage.select(selector2)
])
  .pipe(...)
  .subscribe(values => {
    const parameter: any = values[0];
    const data: any = values[1];
   );
```

In my new project I'm using RxJs 7.5 and this is not possible anymore.

```
combineLatestWith([
  this.userData.controls["name"].valueChanges,
  this.userData.controls["lastName"].valueChanges,
  this.userData.controls["age"].valueChanges,
  this.userData.controls["birthDate"].valueChanges])
.subscribe((result:any) => {

);
```

The compiler says: "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, [unknown, any]>'."

The following snipped looks kind of ugly:

```
this.userData.controls["name"].valueChanges.combineLatestWith([
  this.userData.controls["lastName"].valueChanges,
  this.userData.controls["age"].valueChanges,
  this.userData.controls["birthDate"].valueChanges])
  .subscribe((result: any) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Is there another solution, similar to the first approach?

Comment: You can use 'zip', or 'merge' and give multiple streams. More details you can see here - https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using wrong `combineLatest()` import. Since RxJS 7.0 the creation operator is called `combineLatest()` and is imported from `'rxjs'` (this is the one you want to use).

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

...

combineLatest([firstTimer, secondTimer]).subscribe(...);
```

`combineLatestWith()` is a pipable operator meant to be used inside RxJS chains (thus the error).

```
import { combineLatestWith } from 'rxjs';

...

input1Changes$.pipe(
  combineLatestWith(input2Changes$),
  map(([e1, e2]) => ...)
)
```

Comment: also note that the combineLatestWith can accept variable number of observables to produce the same effect as combineLatest does like this: 
`combineLatestWith(input2Changes$, input3Changes$, input4Changes$)`